# All but the last part of a pipeline is ignored, using sed file | sed file | head file

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to use pipe command in UNIx to substitute some words (sed) and then use the head command to show me the first 9 lines of the file. However, the head command erase the sed command and just do it by itself. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$ sed 's/[n]d/nd STREET/g' street | sed 's/[r]d/rd STREET/g' street | head -n 9 street
01 m motzart        amadeous        25 2nd 94233
02 m guthrie        woody           23 2nd 94223
03 f simone         nina            27 2nd 94112
04 m lennon         john            29 2nd 94221
05 f harris         emmylou         20 2nd 94222
06 m marley         bob             22 2nd 94112
07 f marley         rita            26 2nd 94212
08 f warwick        dione           26 2nd 94222
09 m prine          john            35 3rd 94321
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] for this.  What is content of street?  What do you want as final result?

Comment: The content are some addresses. It is a total of 50 addresses and I want to display only 9 of them adding where is 2nd and 3rd the word street.

Comment: [mcve] means you provide us with a sample data set for input, and expected output.

Comment: Is it how should I describe?

Comment: Your second `sed` is reading from the `street` file, not from the 1st `sed`, defeating the purpose of piping them together.

Comment: Also, you can give just one copy of sed two different operations to run: `sed -e 'thing1' -e 'thing2' file` instead of `sed -e 'thing1' file | sed -e 'thing2'`

Comment: When you say `head -n 9 street` instead of `head -n 9` you make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` and `head` only read from stdin when they aren't given a filename to read from instead. Therefore, when you give `head` the name `street`, it ignores its standard input (which is where the output from `sed` is).

Provide the filename only once, at the front of the pipeline.

```
$ <street sed -e 's/[n]d/nd STREET/g' -e 's/[r]d/rd STREET/g' | head -n 9
```

By the way, you could also write this to use only one sed operation to handle both *nd* and *rd*:

```
$ <streed sed -e 's/\([rn]d\)/&1 STREET/g' | head -n 9
```